# Retrieving from list of objects by id

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In the following code I create a list of three objects and use the variable a,b,c to store the first, second and then the third object by their id's but when I try to store the third object in variable c, it stores a list of the second and third object.

```
class Obj1():
    id='obj1'

class Obj2():
    id='obj2'

class Obj3():
    id='obj3'

list1=[Obj1(),Obj2(),Obj3()]

a=list1[id=="obj1"]
print a

b=list1[id!='obj1']
print b

c=list1[id!='obj1'and id!='obj2':]
print c
```

When I run this code I get :

```
<__main__.Obj1 instance at 0x02AD5DA0>
<__main__.Obj2 instance at 0x02AD9030>
[<__main__.Obj2 instance at 0x02AD9030>, <__main__.Obj3 instance at 0x02AD90A8>]
```

why does variable c contain two objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a dictionary is probably the best idea in this case, as mentioned by Medhat. However, you can do things in a similar way to what you attempted using list comprehensions:

```
a = [e for e in list1 if e.id == "obj1"]
print a

b = [e for e in list1 if e.id != "obj1"]
print b

c = [e for e in list1 if e.id != "obj1" and e.id != "obj2"]
# Or:
# [e for e in list1 if e.id not in ("obj1", "obj2")]
print c
```

Comment: Outside of the example I supplied, the main problem I have is I need to extract from a list of objects inside an object by it's id and this solution worked best. Without having to convert the list into a dictionary your code is most efficient and does exactly what I needed.

Comment: I would add one thing, to retrieve the object as it is from the list : a=[e for e in list1 if e.id != "obj1"][0] . Otherwise the variable stores a list of 1 object

Comment: Glad it helped. As a note, for each new list you construct, the list comprehension has to iterate over every element in the list. Fine for small lists, but if you have very large lists, it could be slow. A simple dictionary lookup runs in constant time, so that's better for large amounts of objects if possible.

Answer (score 2):

`id!='obj1'and id!='obj2'` returns true which equals 1 in Python, that is to say, `c=list1[id!='obj1'and id!='obj2':]` equals `c=list1[1:]` , which of course has two objects.

BTW, `id` is the name of a built-in function. Please avoid using it as a name of varible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dictionary instead:

```
obj1 = Obj1()
obj2 = Obj2()
obj3 = Obj3()
list1 = {obj1.id: obj1, obj2.id: obj2, obj3.id: obj3}
```

Then access your objects like this:

```
a = list1[obj1.id]
b = list1[obj2.id]
c = list1[obj3.id]
```

Comment: by the way you din't answer what he is trying to find :) and he select this is the answer really ? his question is : why does variable c contain two objects?

Comment: Although the other answers explained how a boolean is used as an integer, this answer best solved the main problem of selecting from a list/dictionary using the object's id..

Comment: When you understand what he is trying to do, it is still a valid answer to direct him to the correct path.

Comment: Agreed with Medhat: sometimes it's better to answer what people meant to ask then what they actually asked

Answer (score 1):

Your list1 contains 3 elements:

```
>>> list1
[<__main__.Obj1 instance at 0x103437440>, <__main__.Obj2 instance at 0x1034377a0>,         <__main__.Obj3 instance at 0x103437320>]
>>> id!='obj1'
True
>>> id!='obj2'
True
>>> True and True
True
>>> list1[True:]
[<__main__.Obj2 instance at 0x1034377a0>, <__main__.Obj3 instance at 0x103437320>]
>>>
```

True is 1 and False is 0 index:

Here is the example:

```
>>> ls = [1,2]
>>> ls[True]
2
>>> ls[False]
1
>>>
```

So, list[True:] is equal to list[1:] which is from first element till last.

In your case the the last two elements in the list1.